# Ошибка x**w where w is irrational is not defined for negative x

Tags: python, математика, sympy

Нужно вычислить промежутки возрастания/убывания функции

```
import sympy as sp 
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return (x/(x-1)**2)**(1/3)

x = sp.Symbol("x")

result = sp.solve(sp.diff(f(x)) > 0)
result2 = sp.solve(sp.diff(f(x)) < 0)
```

При запуске программы получаю ошибку:

```
x**w where w is irrational is not defined for negative x
```

Как это можно исправить?